# How to recognize string patterns?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

I want to group strings in python, but I don't really know how to approach the problem.

Lets say I have a list of file names:

```
test-1.jpg
test-2.jpg
test-3.jpg
supertest-828.jpg
supertest-8429.jpg
5-mega-5435-test.jpg
5-mega-453-test.jpg
5-mega-325-test.jpg
```

Now I want to group these by their series names. A good result might be a dict like this:

```
{"test-x.jpg":("test-1.jpg","test-2.jpg","test-3.jpg"), "supertest-x.jpg":(...), "5-mega-x-test.jpg":(...)}
```

Now I wonder what's the best way to approach this problem. I don't want to replace all the numbers in the file name. Instead I need a way to find the number that's changing and just replace this one with an "x" to get the identifier for the series.

So how can I compare strings and identify the part that is not similar?

Possible cave heats are multiple changing numbers requiring 2 or more "x" wildcards and static numbers in the string which shouldn't be changed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: `Cave heats`? You mean `caveats`?

Comment: The completely-disappearing `5-` from the front of the last group does not appear at all explainable by your text -- what's supposed to happen to the last group, **really**?  Please clarify!

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. The 5 should not be changed, because it is static. I strictly want to identify the changing parts only.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

def genericize(s):
    # replace one or more digits with an "x"
    return re.sub("\d+", "x", s)
```

then

```
>>> genericize("test-29.jpg")
'test-x.jpg'
```

and your overall program becomes

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_fnames(lst):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for fname in lst:
        result[genericize(fname)].append(fname)
    return result
```

then

```
fnames = [
    'test-1.jpg',
    'test-2.jpg',
    'test-3.jpg',
    'supertest-828.jpg',
    'supertest-8429.jpg',
    '5-mega-5435-test.jpg',
    '5-mega-453-test.jpg',
    '5-mega-325-test.jpg'
]

print(group_fnames(fnames))
```

gives

```
{
    'supertest-x.jpg': ['supertest-828.jpg', 'supertest-8429.jpg'],
    'test-x.jpg': ['test-1.jpg', 'test-2.jpg', 'test-3.jpg'],
    'x-mega-x-test.jpg': ['5-mega-5435-test.jpg', '5-mega-453-test.jpg', '5-mega-325-test.jpg']
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that it should give 5-mega-x-test.jpg instead of x-mega-x-test.jpg, because the 5 is a constant number and not a sequence. How might that be fixed?

Comment: Identifying static numbers will require another postprocessing pass (because you cannot tell which values are static until you have seen all the files; if you find a "6-mega-18-test.jpg" then 5-etc is _not_ static).